# Residual GRU: ValueError: Inputs have incompatible shapes. Received shapes (5,) and (24,)

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, reshape, shapes, valueerror

I encountered a value error when I tried multivariate input.
This is the error that I got:

```
ValueError: Inputs have incompatible shapes. Received shapes (5,) and (24,)
```

This is the shape of my input:

```
X shape (2100, 84, 5)
y shape (2100, 24)
```

This is my model summary:

```
Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 input_2 (InputLayer)           [(None, 80, 5)]      0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 lstm_1 (LSTM)                  (None, 80, 24)       2880        ['input_2[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 lstm_2 (LSTM)                  (None, 80, 24)       4704        ['lstm_1[0][0]']                 
                                                                                                  
 add (Add)                      (None, 80, 24)       0           ['lstm_1[0][0]',                 
                                                                  'lstm_2[0][0]']                 
                                                                                                  
 lambda (Lambda)                (None, 24)           0           ['add[0][0]']                    
                                                                                                  
 lstm_3 (LSTM)                  (None, 24)           4704        ['add[0][0]']                    
                                                                                                  
 add_1 (Add)                    (None, 24)           0           ['lambda[0][0]',                 
                                                                  'lstm_3[0][0]']                 
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 12,288
Trainable params: 12,288
Non-trainable params: 0
```

This is my code for the model:

```
def make_residual_lstm_layers(input, rnn_width, rnn_depth, rnn_dropout):
    
    x = input
    for i in range(rnn_depth):
        return_sequences = i < rnn_depth - 1
        x_rnn = LSTM(rnn_width, recurrent_dropout=rnn_dropout, dropout=rnn_dropout, return_sequences=return_sequences)(x)
        if return_sequences:
           
            if i > 0 or input.shape[-1] == rnn_width:
                x = add([x, x_rnn])
            else:
               
                x = x_rnn
        else:
           
            def slice_last(x):
                return x[..., -1, :]
            x = add([Lambda(slice_last)(x), x_rnn])
    return x
```

This is how I defined the input:

```
input = Input(shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]))
output = make_residual_lstm_layers(input, rnn_width=24, rnn_depth=d, rnn_dropout=e)
model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)
```

This is the full error that I received:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-973dead00adb> in <module>
      1 hyper = Hyperactive()
      2 hyper.add_search(rlstm, search_space, optimizer=optimizer, n_iter=100)
----> 3 hyper.run()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\hyperactive\hyperactive.py in run(self, max_time)
    136             opt.max_time = max_time
    137 
--> 138         self.results_list = run_search(
    139             self.opt_pros, self.distribution, self.n_processes
    140         )

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\hyperactive\run_search.py in run_search(opt_pros, distribution, n_processes)
     49 
     50     if n_processes == 1:
---> 51         results_list = single_process(_process_, process_infos)
     52     else:
     53         (distribution, process_func), dist_paras = _get_distribution(distribution)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\hyperactive\distribution.py in single_process(process_func, process_infos)
      9 
     10 def single_process(process_func, process_infos):
---> 11     results = [process_func(*info) for info in process_infos]
     12 
     13     return results

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\hyperactive\distribution.py in <listcomp>(.0)
      9 
     10 def single_process(process_func, process_infos):
---> 11     results = [process_func(*info) for info in process_infos]
     12 
     13     return results

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\hyperactive\process.py in _process_(nth_process, optimizer)
      5 
      6 def _process_(nth_process, optimizer):
----> 7     optimizer.search(nth_process)
      8 
      9     return {

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\hyperactive\optimizers\gfo_wrapper.py in search(self, nth_process)
    137         gfo_objective_function = gfo_wrapper_model(self.s_space())
    138 
--> 139         self._optimizer.search(
    140             objective_function=gfo_objective_function,
    141             n_iter=self.n_iter,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gradient_free_optimizers\search.py in search(self, objective_function, n_iter, max_time, max_score, early_stopping, memory, memory_warm_start, verbosity)
    133             if self.stop.check(self.start_time, self.p_bar.score_best, self.score_l):
    134                 break
--> 135             self._initialization(init_pos, nth_iter)
    136 
    137         self.finish_initialization()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gradient_free_optimizers\times_tracker.py in wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
     25         def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
     26             t = time.time()
---> 27             res = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
     28             self.iter_times.append(time.time() - t)
     29             return res

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gradient_free_optimizers\search.py in _initialization(self, init_pos, nth_iter)
     55         self.init_pos(init_pos)
     56 
---> 57         score_new = self._score(init_pos)
     58         self.evaluate(score_new)
     59 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gradient_free_optimizers\times_tracker.py in wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
     16         def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
     17             t = time.time()
---> 18             res = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
     19             self.eval_times.append(time.time() - t)
     20             return res

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gradient_free_optimizers\search.py in _score(self, pos)
     46     @TimesTracker.eval_time
     47     def _score(self, pos):
---> 48         return self.score(pos)
     49 
     50     @TimesTracker.iter_time

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gradient_free_optimizers\results_manager.py in _wrapper(pos)
     29             value = self.conv.position2value(pos)
     30             para = self.conv.value2para(value)
---> 31             results_dict = self._obj_func_results(objective_function, para)
     32 
     33             self.results_list.append({**results_dict, **para})

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gradient_free_optimizers\results_manager.py in _obj_func_results(self, objective_function, para)
     12 
     13     def _obj_func_results(self, objective_function, para):
---> 14         results = objective_function(para)
     15 
     16         if isinstance(results, tuple):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gradient_free_optimizers\memory.py in wrapper(para)
     43                 return self.memory_dict[pos_tuple]
     44             else:
---> 45                 score = objective_function(para)
     46 
     47                 self.memory_dict[pos_tuple] = score

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\hyperactive\optimizers\objective_function.py in _model(para)
     35             para = gfo2hyper(search_space, para)
     36             self.para_dict = para
---> 37             results = self.objective_function(self)
     38 
     39             return results

<ipython-input-13-5b4490c109de> in rlstm(opt)
     50     print("q shape",q.shape)
     51     input = Input(shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]))
---> 52     output = make_residual_lstm_layers(input, rnn_width=24, rnn_depth=d, rnn_dropout=e)
     53     model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)
     54     model.summary()

<ipython-input-4-8c85b2bfe824> in make_residual_lstm_layers(input, rnn_width, rnn_depth, rnn_dropout)
     22             def slice_last(x):
     23                 return x[..., -1, :]
---> 24             x = add([Lambda(slice_last)(x), x_rnn])
     25     return x

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\merge.py in add(inputs, **kwargs)
    786 
    787   """
--> 788   return Add(**kwargs)(inputs)
    789 
    790 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65     except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68     finally:
     69       del filtered_tb

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\merge.py in _compute_elemwise_op_output_shape(self, shape1, shape2)
     76       else:
     77         if i != j:
---> 78           raise ValueError(
     79               'Inputs have incompatible shapes. '
     80               f'Received shapes {shape1} and {shape2}')

ValueError: Inputs have incompatible shapes. Received shapes (5,) and (24,)
```

​

Comment: Please always include complete error messages and/or tracebacks, or else you will have people guessing which line of this code produces the error.

Comment: I already included it, thank you